# connection refused to localhost:8080

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes and not sure what prerequisite I'm missing in order to make it work.

I ran the following command

```
kubectl create -f k8s-pod.yml
```

and the response is

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you
>   specify the right host or port?

**k8s-pod.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod

metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    language: go
    env: test

spec:
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: app:1.0.8
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Where are you trying this ? local setup, gcp, aws etc ?

Comment: yes it's a local setup

Comment: You will have to setup minikube to be able to use kubernetes on local

Comment: You can't access pod directly you need to make Service for same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check if you can connect to kubernetes cluster using the below command

```
kubectl get cs
```

if you get an error that means you cant connect to kubernetes api server. check your kubernetes setup

Comment: the response is `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "cs"`, it's a local setup and i'm new to this.

Comment: that means you cant connect to kubernetes api server. how did you do local setup?

Comment: honestly I didn't do any setup, I just assumed everything came along with docker that I just installed, my surprise was that how come I've a command kubectl available in my terminal, seems like I need to install or setup something, can you please guide me, it's kubernetes 101 for me

Comment: the tutorial I'm following didn't do any setup, it went straight into running commands in the terminal and i'm following the same.

Comment: In order to start on your local machine please follow f.e. local Minikube installation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you get this error when you are not having the root user privileges.
Try

```
sudo su
```